# Validation in Laravel. How to transfer the rule and message to the controller?

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I am having problems displaying custom error messages.
I received a training project that had the following code:

```
class StoreProject extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:projects,name|max:255',
            'website' => 'url',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
           return [
                'name' => 'Це імʼя вже використовується',
                'website' => 'Будь-ласка введіть адресу вашого сайту вірно http://...'
            ];
    }
}
```

I added the function message( ) myself.

This is the controller code:

```
public function store(StoreProject $request)
{

    $project = new Project($request->except('project_image'));

    $project->owner_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $project->status_id = StatusProject::UNCONFIRMED;

    //send email to moderator and accountant for the moderation
    if( $project->save() ) {
        $this->dispatch(new ConfirmNewProject($project));
    }

    // load image from cropie serves
    if ($request->has('project_image')) {
        $file = self::croppie($request->input("project_image"));
        $project->uploadImage($file, 1);
    }

    return redirect()->route('projects.show', [$project->id]);
}
```

I tried various methods: withErrors([]) and this method:

```
'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
            'name' => 'Це імʼя вже використовується',
            'website' => 'Будь-ласка введіть адресу вашого сайту вірно http://...'
        ],
    ]
```

but when checking, I get the key value, not the text of the error message

Errors:
validation.unique
validation.url

How to transfer the rule and message to the controller?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the `messages()` function like that one:

```
public function messages()
{
       return [
            'name.required' => 'Name required message',
            'name.unique' => 'Name unique message',
            'name.max' => 'Name max message',
            'website.url' => 'Будь-ласка введіть адресу вашого сайту вірно http://...'
        ];
}
```